# Authenticating via LDAP for the current windows user's credentials?

Tags: php

We have an app that is hosted on our intranet in a Windows desktop using WAMP (W for Windows, P for PHP). We need to implement a new functionality - validate user's by using his / her windows logged in credentials whenever user visits our intranet site.

Here I lack some basic concepts of implementing it - how can I access current windows logged in user details in PHP.

Is there any way to detect out who the current user is and pass this users data for validation to our LDAP server for verification?

Comment: PHP doesn't provide authentication, the web server does. In your case, Apache isn't really designed for integrated Windows authentication, although modules have been written for it. On the other hand if you could switch to IIS then you would get integrated authentication for free.

Comment: You could access environment variables, which could tell you the username — but only if the user, and not the server, is running the application.

Comment: @Neil : Thanks for the information. Can you please let us know how IIS would help us to meet the objective? Note that at server side we are using PHP scripts. Hence as such for LDAP verification I need to have the user details within my PHP script. Getting from env variable is bit risky as it may be overridden. Note that we can have user logging from MAC / Linux desktop also

Comment: @Prakash You would alter the IIS configuration to disallow anonymous access and enable integrated authentication. IIS would then negotiate authentication with Internet Explorer. Then it would set the HTTP_AUTH_USER server variable to the username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use mod_auth_sspi - Apache 2.x authentication module. It is very easy to setup.

Here is the homepage http://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-auth-sspi/

You can protect locations, folders, or specific files. You can allow/deny specific users, groups, domains etc.

I implemented this on a windows 2008 server running apache 2.2 and PHP 5.2 and it worked flawlessly for my SSO.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look here : http://siphon9.net/loune/2007/10/simple-lightweight-ntlm-in-php/

Is 1 half of authentication.

Just a note apache needs to have **KeepAlive On** setting set.

It will give you current user's login/domain/workstation information.

If you need full NTLM authentication scheme support, your web server needs module for it.

Look here : http://modntlm.sourceforge.net/

and here : http://bloke.org/linux/ntlm-authentication-active-directory-on-apache-linux/

Inboth cases, URL needs to be in "Trusted zone" for IE and similar setup for firefox.

Comment: We have user having MAC / Linux desktops Would the above solution work for them - I mean that would we be able to retrieve details if they visit our intranet site using browser in MAC / Linux desktops?

Comment: No, you asked for "Authenticating via LDAP for the current windows user's credentials" - no MAC no Linux

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - the issue that initially they all would be windows OS later they can change their desktops to MAC / Linux but their credentials remains the same to access our org n/w