# Get Windows username of current user using php?

Tags: php, windows-users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to read Windows loged in username with PHP/IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899643/how-to-read-windows-loged-in-username-with-php-iis)

I'm work on php tool that generate Data Access layer and generate some folders and files to user but i need to know how can i get username for current windows user to generate these folders on desktop

```
ex:
C:\\users\\<username>\\desktop
```

I need to know the username.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read Windows loged in username with PHP/IIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899643/how-to-read-windows-loged-in-username-with-php-iis) or perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299089/authenticating-via-ldap-for-the-current-windows-users-credentials?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The question is regarding current windows user who runs php-cgi. The answer marked as correct, but actually shows wrong data. Run `<?php echo get_current_user(); ?>` to show current php user. If impersonation is turned on in php.ini `fastcgi.impersonate = 1` then `IUSR` (default IIS User) will be shown by default, otherwise `IIS AppPool\[your website app pool]`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If by current windows user you mean the user running the script then that is set in an environment variable which you can get using:

```
<?php echo getenv("username"); ?>
```

If you want to get the home directory of the user running the script you should use

```
<?php echo getenv("HOMEDRIVE") . getenv("HOMEPATH"); ?>
```

This should output either C:\Users\Fred or C:\Documents and Settings\Fred depending on if you are using windows Vista/7 or windows XP.

To see all of the environment variables you can do:

```
<?php global $_ENV; var_dump($_ENV); ?>
```

Comment: This gave me the current machine name not user whose use this machine now 
ex if your machine name =python and current logging user name =Moataz it will get python not moataz and i want username moataz to create folders on this desktop,
there is any way to do that.

Comment: Thanks in advance your post add to me more knowledge.
Thanks

Comment: Same problem than moataz, the returned string is the computer name, not logged username...

Comment: btw. it's the current computer name where the script is running on as far as the computer has one.

Comment: Also access to `$_ENV` depends upon the php.ini setting `variables_order = "GPCS"` and `E` is normally turned OFF for obvious security reasons

Comment: not sure why this is marked as an answer. If you use php on iis, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899643/how-to-read-windows-logged-in-username-with-php-iis/3903024#3903024) should be the answer. also, make sure you are not using anonymous authentication.